# How to join array in array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the output like below:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

But I wish to have the output like below:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Actually I have 3 array together inside a

```
 a[1]= [1,2,3]
 a[2]= [4,5,6]
 a[3]= [7,8,9]
```

Anyone has an idea on how to join the array in the array to produce the output above?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try the code I have in my answer below? The three lines you added for filling up `a` do not look like valid Matlab code. Are you using `numpy` by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

So `a` is meant to be an multi-array like follows:

```
a = [1,2,3];
a(:,:,2) = [4,5,6];
a(:,:,3) = [7,8,9];
```

To convert it to a row vector we can do

```
b = reshape(a,1,9)
```